# I need to move multiple files from multiple folders up one level without deleting the source folders

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have this directory structure in Windows 10: `\groups\lrc\timesheets\[staff member name]\inbox\[staffmembertimesheet].xls`.

I want to move the files up to the [staff member name] folder and leave the \inbox folder for the next cycle where staff members drop their timesheets.

I got this script from another thread here and it moves the files, but it also deletes the source folder \inbox.

```
for /f "delims==" %i in ('dir /a:d /b') do for /f "delims==" %f in ('dir "%i" /a:d /b') do (move "%i\%f\*"
```

I assume I can modify this to leave the folder, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to do so.

Comment: Simplistic solution: at end of script, use *mkdir* to recreate the folder.

Comment: Good idea. However, I have to create a folder named inbox at the bottom of each staff member path, so that's nine folders. one under each staff member's folder, named inbox.

Comment: Write 9 lines in one script, use once each time. However, it is also a maintenance issue, because script will need to be changed as new members are added.

Comment: The simple method you suggested works great, thanks.  But I'd still like to build a script with variables.  I'm studying up.